# the function setTimeout does not work on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I wrote a server and locally everything works great, but after deploy it to heroku setTimeout is executed instantly and without delay. Tried to deploy `setTimeout(openCard(buttonIndex), 1000)`, timeoutID is global variable. Aclually don't what to do

```
const clickButton = (client, buttonIndex, time) => {
  if(!(users[client.id])['isMaster']) {
    if(room.teamTurn === (users[client.id])['team'] && !arrayToPlay[buttonIndex].isClicked && room.gameStarted && !globaleTime.MasterTurn) {
      if(room[room.teamTurn].length > 1) {
        addChosenWord(client,buttonIndex);
      }
      wordChosen = chosenWordCorrect() ? buttonIndex : null;
      io.emit('wordChosen', wordChosen);
      if(wordChosen !== null){
        clearTimeout(timeoutID);
        const date = new Date();
        const localTimeOffset = date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
        const offset = date.getTime() - localTimeOffset - time;
        timeoutID = setTimeout(()=>openCard(buttonIndex), 1000 + offset);
        } else {
          clearTimeout(timeoutID)
          io.emit('room', room);
        }
    } else {
      io.emit('buttonClicked', buttonIndex,client.id);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You haven't provided us with any debugging details. Is script file loading? Any errors in dev tools console? etc. Take a few minutes to go through [ask]

Comment: Before going much further, try logging the value of `offset`. If it's negative, perhaps because heroku is running in a different time zone, re-check the validity of steps used to calculate `const offset`.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you have in the code `setTimeout(() => openCard(buttonIndex), 1000 + offset);` but in your ask `setTimeout(openCard(buttonIndex), 1000)`.

Check if the `openCard` is inside an arrow function in the `setTimeout`.

Comment: I meant that I wrote like this, but it is still executed instantly
```setTimeout(() => openCard(buttonIndex), 1000);```
open card function: ```const openCard = (buttonIndex) => {...}```

Answer (score 0):

`date.getTime()` returns a time stamp based on the UTC time zone <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)</sup>.

- If the `time` argument comes from a `date.getTIme` call on the front end, the server should not be adjusting it for the time zone of the server.

  *Solution*: remove local time zone adjustment on the server.
- If the front end is sending the time based on local time, it would also need to notify the server what time zone it is in.

  *Solution*: change the time sent from the client to use UTC time zone ***and*** remove local time zone adjustment on the server.

Most likely the code works locally because the server's time zone is the same as the client's, and deploying it to a server in another time zone breaks the current logic for calculating the timer millisecond count.

---

Assuming that `time` is in the UTC time zone, *and that the objective is to open a card a second after clicking the button taking into account the time the request takes to reach the server*, this example attempts to calculate a suitable delay:

```
if(wordChosen !== null){
  clearTimeout(timeoutID);
  // time in UTC zone:

  let requestTime = Date.now() - time;
  requestTime = Math.max( 20, requestTime); // not too low or negative
  const responseFactor = 0; // 0 to ignore;
  let delayTime = 1000 - requestTime - requestTime*responseFactor;
  delayTime = Math.max(0, delayTime); // non negative

  timeoutID = setTimeout(()=>openCard(buttonIndex), delayTime);
}
```

Set `responseFactor` to a number between 0 and 1 to include an estimate of the response time based on the request time.

Comment: Even if we discard actions with time and put a fixed value, it will still execute immediately.

Comment: @Jorra, That should help. Could you copy and paste the `setTImeout` line from the test that called the timer callback immediately (without using `time`)  and put it in the question - it cuts down the test code a lot. Please do not just type in the code that failed from memory if you have changed it since.